# Adding data to pushpin

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

this is my codes for the pushpin on the Bing Map.

```
        MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        Pushpin pin1 = new Pushpin();
        GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate();
        geo.Latitude = 1.369963;
        geo.Longitude = 103.849275;
        pin1.Location = geo;
        layer.Children.Add(pin1);
        Pushpin pin2 = new Pushpin();
        GeoCoordinate geo1 = new GeoCoordinate();
        geo1.Latitude = 1.350678;
        geo1.Longitude = 103.848224;
        pin2.Location = geo1;
        layer.Children.Add(pin2);
        map1.Children.Add(layer);
```

How do I add information(Address, tel no.) to both the pushpin?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put something into the Pushpin's [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) property. That might be a simple string

```
pin1.Content = "Hello, World.";
```

or something more complex like a panel with some child elements:

```
var panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(...);
...
pin1.Content = panel;
```

---

In a second step you would perhaps define a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) and either assign it to the Pushpin's [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) property or let it automatically be applied by setting its [DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Restaurant">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now you would simply assign or bind your item data class (`Restaurant` here, which has the `Name` and `Address` properties) to the Pushpin's `Content`.

Comment: Thanks you! Can you explain more about adding a panel with some child elements.

Comment: Start reading the [WPF Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) or about the [Silverlight Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).